# Worktree in VS2022?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I need to work in two branches at the same time in VS 2022. I took my git repository and created a new work tree in a separate folder for the feature branch I need to work with via the CLI.

When I open that solution in VS, none of the git tooling works and it doesn't even understand the repository it's working with. Git works fine via the CLI though. Does 2022 (17.3) support worktree? I have seen some people say it does and some say it doesn't, but can't seem to find any real documentation on the Git tooling in VS with it.

Answer (score 2):

As worktrees is an experimental feature of git (check the [Bugs section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_bugs) in the worktree docs).

Therefore tooling support is going to lag behind.

Just stick to the CLI when in a worktree.